# Is it more efficient to mutex lock a variable multiple times in a code-block, or just lock the whole code-block?

Tags: c++, mutex

If we have the following code example:

```
if (letsDoThis) //bool
{
    sharedVar++; // This is shared across other threads.
          :
    sharedVar++;
          :
    sharedVar++;
          :
    sharedVar++;
          :
    sharedVar++;
}
```

Where each `:` is like ~10 lines of code (no slow function calls or anything). Would it be faster to write code such that you lock a mutex around the whole "if" block (well, the contents of the if block), or to lock and unlock over each individual sharedVar usage?

If it is a "it depends" type question, then which approach (maybe as a rule of thumb) is better to start with?

Finally how can you determine which of the two runs faster on your system? - would a trace tool really show you useful data in a meaningful way?

Comment: Why can you not do `var += N` once? Can you add some context?

Comment: Why not use an atomic type for `sharedVar`?

Comment: It's not a question of which is "faster", it's a question of what concurrency issues you're trying to guard against.

Comment: @bobah ah, that's a really good point. But it highlights a poor example on my part. I use mutex's quite alot because I am using QNX : ( I don't really have simple examples to put up so I tried to manufacture one. Let's say I have to call the `++` operation as I have it in my example. The question really is just about how best to use mutex for this (poor) example.

Comment: If the code block's logic takes into account that sharedVar can be changed by other threads while it is executing, then you can lock each access separately, but intuition tells me that this is almost never the case. Also, if there are multiple access operations that are very close to each other, my guess is that the overhead of locking and releasing the mutex may be a little high, so unless your locked out thread must be very responsive, it seems best to lock the whole block (barring special considerations).

Comment: @Yuushi actually in this example, that is a good point. But I really want to know a bit more about mutex "best practise" for this question... though I have read that mutex's use at least one atomic anyway :o

Comment: Note that this question is also platform and implementation specific e.g. Linux uses a futex implementation (fast userspace mutex), which means in a no-contention case, there is no system call (Windows CRITICAL_SECTION is similar, I believe). Whether `std::mutex` is implemented using these primitives is not standardized, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends (among all the other tings that impact performance) on

- How many threads and cores you have (the min of both is relevant)
- How much time threads spend in that part of the code (and other parts that lock the mutex)

From the perspective of a single thread, multiple locks and unlocks mean additional work and are - especially under congestion - rather expensive/timeconsuming and it will probably lead to more cache ping pong between the cores. So it will slow down the performance of a single thread. However, if multiple locks and unlocks reduce the total amount of time a thread holds the mutex in each iteration, then this means, there can be more parallelism in your program and the overal performance scales better with the number of threads and CPU cores.

Both effects might be negligable, both effects might be significant and if the code isn't in the hotpath of your program, it might not matter in the first place. I think the only thing, you can do to determine what is better in your case is to just run both variants and measure overall throughput. If you don't see a difference, I'd probably go with a single lock and unlock (i.e. with a `std::lock_guard`) for simplicity.

The general question you should ask however is, if you really need so much synchronization between the threads and if you have to synchronize multiple times: If it is ok that other threads don't see intermediate values of the shared state (which you can't guarantee anyway if they don't wait for each other), then why don't you combine all the operations on the shared state and make it a single operation at the end of the block?

And of course, if your shared state is indeed only a single integer, then you should just use atomics and get rid of the mutex altogether.

Comment: In the context of a single thread and in general under no contention on Linux locks are only invoking user space code and are very cheap.

Comment: @bobah: Correct, but if there is low contention, it might be even cheaper to only lock and unlock it once. Also locking and unlocking introduces synchonization barriers, which might reduce the level of optimization the compiler is able to perform and increase memory access times (as the caches must synchronize). Wether those effects are relevant or not can only be determined on the actual system, for the actual code for the actual workload.

Comment: Ok, this gives me a good starting point to go with : )   It is difficult to know how expensive a lock will be - as you say it depends on the circumstance, so go for the more simple implementation first and optimise later.

Answer (score 1):

If the code between subsequent increments is allowed run concurrently from the program logic point of view then your best course is to use the atomic counter. If whatever is done before a counter increment needs to be immediately visible to other threads then increment with the `release` semantics (atomic increment plus barrier), else - with `relaxed`(just the atomic increment).

If for whatever reason atomic increment is not an option then benchmark your mutex ideas in a simple test application running the subject code concurrently in a loop. `google benchmark` is a nice little library that can save you some typing. If you only have raw Posix threads you can borrow [my old code](http://bobah.net/d4d/source-code/misc/context-switch-benchmark-posix-cpp).

Comment: I honestly do get the point about atomics, so I have +1'd you for this very relevant answer and the nice bench mark code (which I will try to apply in my platform - arm a8 running QNX). But for me, unless I re-factor a load of existing code (which is looking more likely as the days go on) I am stuck with the humble mutex.